# Low cost FTDI cables?

Tags: usb, rs232, ftdi

I'm looking for USB to serial FTDI cables. However, the cheapest I can find is $20 US each, which is *way* too expensive, given my price target for the entire product is $70. I'm hoping they can be found for $5 each somewhere, but even FTDI themselves has them for £16 (about $25) each. Anyone know of any other options?

Comment: You could just make the user supply their own "batteries not included"

Comment: @Joby Taffey, that is an option if I can't find a cheap one. But the cable brings a lot more features; without it, you can only use the default settings of the module, and you can't download the data from the datalog.

Comment: The FTDI FT232RL device is $4.50 alone, so I don't think you will have any luck, at least with FTDI devices. (http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=768-1007-1-ND )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nokia data cables are USB to serial.

http://hackaday.com/2010/02/25/nokia-usb-cable-is-usb-to-serial-in-disguise/

You might also want to look at non-FTDI serial to USB chips, like the Prolific 2303 (PL2303) which is in this Nokia cable.

Comment: Brilliant. I could hack these myself, or, do you know of someone selling pre-hacked cables?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, I just remembered the article

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the PL2303 is far more reliable than FTDI.  They both do the same job though.

You can find a full adapter here for under $4:
http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.5859

If you do a Google Product Search for PL2303, you will find others.

Comment: The Windows drivers for these can be very shaky, though.

Comment: @XTL Agreed, I have found this also.

Comment: @XTL, odd, I've used it on Windows and Linux with no issues.  Interesting.  Perhaps I am using an older driver version?  I haven't updated in a few years.

Answer (score 3):

Why not design in your own USB/UART device on the board? All these cables have in them is an FTDI FT232R or similar

Comment: Space restrictions.

Comment: Having it off-board might be useful for users that have several of the products... maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your product already has a micro, the cheapest way is usually to use one with onboard USB.

Comment: Yeah I was considering this but adding a USB port will be bigger than the 6 pin header and the USB/UART would only be used while on the ground (normally is flying in a plane.)

Comment: @Thomas: Micro USB is smaller than a 6-pin header.

Comment: @Nick T, Micro USB, never heard of it! I was thinking of using a Mini USB type B socket. Either way directly adding USB probably isn't an option at the moment, I don't think my MCU supports it.